# map is loading but can't see the map in my application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am learning Android development.

I am using the Google map API, to display a map. I have done all the steps according to the tutorial.

when i try to view the application in my device, the application loads I can see the Google logo but map is not visible. (i see the white background with Google logo at the bottom).

I have added my code and the screenshot. can someone please help me to fix this. thank you..

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebSq.jpg)

`activity_maps.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

`MapsActivity.java` file

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
     * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device.
     * This method will only be triggered once the user has installed
     Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21, 57);
        mMap.addMarker(new
                MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Tutorialspoint.com"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TutorialsPoint));
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shreefood">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ShreeFood">

        <!--
             TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

             To get one, follow the directions here:

                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

             Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
             project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
             "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
        -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY API KEY" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="            Shree Food Service"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="   Welcome to Shree Food Service"
            android:textAlignment="center">
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

can someone please help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest reading the note in the `AndroidManifest.xml` which you posted - look for the `TODO:` section.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow the directions here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

Once you have your API key (it starts with "**AIza**"), define a new property in your project's

> local.properties

file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the

> YOUR_API_KEY

string in this file with

> ${MAPS_API_KEY}

Or add this API_KEY in Manifest.xml file

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API KEY" />   //Add your key here
```

Hope this helps you to understand with URL.